# QT - QListView - currentSelection/currentChanged is not emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I cannot obtain signal emit on selection change in QListView.

So far I have tried multiple things, but only those got connected without debugger complaining:

```
// Approach 1
    QStandardItemModel *standardModel = new QStandardItemModel(ui->instr_list);
    ui->instr_list->setModel(standardModel);
    QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->instr_list->selectionModel();
    connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)), this, SLOT (update_bin_instr(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)));
```

```
// Approach 2
    QStandardItemModel *standardModel = new QStandardItemModel(ui->instr_list);
    ui->instr_list->setModel(standardModel);
    QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->instr_list->selectionModel();
    connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)), this, SLOT (update_bin_instr(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)));
```

instr_list is QListView

The signal should get emitted, but nothing happens. Can somebody please point out the obvious thing (to some of you) what I am doing wrong? :-)

Comment: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50337-Can-t-I-modify-qlistview-s-item-can-i-modify-only-qlistwidget-s-item

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez: Thanks for the reply. This link describes a problem with editing. I don't have any issue with this here. I can't get selectionModel to emit the signal, when selection of QLIstView is changed.

Comment: i tried a test and update gets triggered when i change selection. QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->listView->selectionModel();
    connect(selectionModel, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged,
            this,   &MainWindow::Update);

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez: Would it be possible for you  to share the full example? I cannot make it work and I have already wasted a day on this... :-( In my case selectionModel is 0. nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you want update_bin_instr to get triggered everytime you change a selection in your qlistview.

// in mainwindow.h i added

```
private slots:
    void Update(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous);

private:
QStringListModel        *m_Model;
QItemSelectionModel     *selectionModel;
```

// in the main window constructor.

```
m_Model = new QStringListModel();
QStringList list;
list << "a" << "b" << "c";

m_Model->setStringList(list);
ui->listView->setModel(m_Model);

selectionModel = ui->listView->selectionModel();
connect(selectionModel, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, &MainWindow::Update);

}
```

// everytime i change selection update gets called.

```
void MainWindow::Update(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
{
    qDebug() << "changed" << "current" << current.row() << "previous" << previous.row();
}
```

Comment: With your example I made it work as well. I missed stringModel->setStringList(list); As a new guy to Qt, I just couldn't figure it out. Now it works. Thank you for this example.